# How to prevent Dropzonejs from moving the fallback element to the bottom of the page?

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

Dropzone moves my fallback input field to the bottom of the page - which doesen't looks great because the whole body is the dropzone. Is there a way to prevent this behaviour and force dropzone to let the fallback input where it's been placed by me?

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution. I case someone has the same problem I share it with you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 Dropzone.options.firedrop = {
    fallback: function () { fallback(); },
    forceFallback:false
  };

function fallback() {
        console.log("DZ fallback function");
    }
});
```